# Closing right/left tabs in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, tabs, autohotkey

How do you close all the tabs to the right/left of the current tab in Notepad++?

Is there a plugin or an autohotkey script that can achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to close all the tabs to the right of the current tab *or* all the tabs to the left of the current tab? If you want to do both, i.e closing all the tabs but the current one, then see Dave Rook's answer.

Comment: I want to close all the tabs to the right of the current tab or all the tabs to the left of the current tab but not both. What I want is available in firefox & chrome when you right click the tab context menu and select close tab to the right/close tab to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Notepad++ 6.5 onwards**, there is a `Close All to the Left, Close All to the Right` option added to the **Tab Context/ Right Click Menu** as shown in the image below.

[image: Notepad++ Tab Right Click Menu]

Answer (score 1):

You should have an option built in - right click on the tab you want to keep open and select "Close ALL But This"